# Frequency that a value occurs in a data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame `df1` :

```
 id | action | 
----|--------|
 1  | A      | 
 1  | A      | 
 2  | C      | 
 3  | D      |
 2  | B      |
 2  | C      |   
 1  | B      | 
 3  | D      | 
 1  | D      |
 3  | A      |
```

I want to count the frequency that the value `action` appear for each user, and put this value in new column. I want to get the following data frame :

```
 id | action=A | action=B | action=C |
----|----------|----------|----------|       
 1  | 2        |  1       |  0       |
 2  | 0        |  1       |  2       |
 3  | 1        |  0       |  0       |
```

Comment: Do you have any code so far? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should add an other column `Count` with the value `1`

```
df['Count'] = 1
df
id  action  Count
0   1   A   1
1   1   A   1
2   2   C   1
3   3   D   1
4   2   B   1
5   2   C   1
6   1   B   1
7   3   D   1
8   1   D   1
9   3   A   1
```

Then you can use `pivot_table()` to get the desired result.

```
df.pivot_table('Count', index='id', columns='action', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
action  A   B   C   D
id              
1   2   1   0   1
2   0   1   2   0
3   1   0   0   2
```

Comment: that's it - i was missing that additional column. +1

Comment: @MaxU Yes, the additional column makes it easy to count

Answer (score 0):

I've found one solution, but i don't like it:

```
import six
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = """\
id  action  
 1  A       
 1  A       
 2  C       
 3  D      
 2  B      
 2  C         
 1  B       
 3  D       
 1  D      
 3  A        
"""

df = pd.read_csv(six.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
print(df)

pvt = df.pivot(columns='action', values='id')
pvt['id'] = df['id']
print(pvt.groupby('id').count().reset_index().to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
   id action
0   1      A
1   1      A
2   2      C
3   3      D
4   2      B
5   2      C
6   1      B
7   3      D
8   1      D
9   3      A
 id  A  B  C  D
  1  2  1  0  1
  2  0  1  2  0
  3  1  0  0  2
```

PS i hope there will be another, more elegant ones